# Ember - selectize error -- You modified "focused" twice

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember selectize field - and when I create the item - it adds it to be my dropdown ok - but it does not autoselect it. I've tried to set the model and this works, but it produces an error. Not sure what it means or how to rectify.

https://ember-twiddle.com/9f3883fc1155a7bc9cb43c212643843d?openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route

in my actions I have something like this

```
     createItem(item) {
       console.log("create ", item);
       this.set('references', this.get('references').addObject({reference:item}));//add item to references and set the referenc.agenda.method.valuees
       //this line here creates the error.
       this.set('model.campaignReference', item);//set the campaign reference in the model
     },
```

the error

```
EmberError {description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber: undefined, message: "Assertion Failed: You modified "focused" twice on …m/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13948 for more details.", name: "Error", …}
```

Comment: getting this error - https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13948

Comment: So I reproduced the behavior you described that you want in the twiddle you linked here: https://ember-twiddle.com/d0fe072a3ecbf5188b8984a54100c536?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C, things appear to be working in general. This leads me to believe that setting your campaignReference may be triggering something more complicated, since it seems to work in the simple case. Any chance you can reproduce the problem in the twiddle?

Comment: @pzuraq  -- it would be a multiple=false -- but when I create item - I appear unable to push it to the model -- I fetch from the db the current list -- then set the model on select -- delete the item and add a new item - and then it empties the model? complains when I try and set it

Comment: Alright so I did it for `multiple=false` as well: https://ember-twiddle.com/d0fe072a3ecbf5188b8984a54100c536?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C

Comment: -- I think mine has value -- so it sets the initial value when the model gets replenished on init -- so I was wondering if having the value -- and the selected interfere with each other?

Comment: it does look like `value` doesn't really like this behavior for some reason, I would try using `selection` instead since that seems to work.

Comment: -- but then you need to set the model - to set the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170238/discussion-between-pzuraq-and-the-old-county).

Comment: @pzuraq - I've stopped work on this for the day - how do I save these twiddles? I am unsure how to fix this issue. Its very complex in the integration here

Comment: There's a link in the upper left hand menu, "Save to GitHub gist", you'll need to sign into github to be able to use it

Comment: If I delete the value -- then it won't show in the input -- so I still have this issue of it not setting the value on load -- and setting the value on create item.

Comment: need to figure out how to do an auto select on this selectize

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/d4a39ecef558d68dd2bf8a776ed85440?openFiles=controllers.my-route.js%2C&route=%2Fmy-route  - I think its the way we tried to add the selectize to other form input types -- like maybe an action is getting null as it goes through - we tried to use it as a sub component